# Combine Stacked bars and Lines into a same graph with categorical variables

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(rsdmx)
library(dplyr)
library(countrycode)

dt<-as.data.frame(readSDMX("http://widukind-api.cepremap.org/api/v1/sdmx/IMF/data/IFS/..Q.BFPA-BP6-USD"))
AP<-rename(dt, Country=WIDUKIND_NAME, Year=TIME_PERIOD,A.PI.T=OBS_VALUE)     
AP<-AP[c("Country","REF-AREA","Year","A.PI.T")]
AP$Country<-countrycode(AP$`REF-AREA`, "imf","iso3c")
AP$A.PI.T<-as.numeric((as.character(AP$A.PI.T)))
AP$Country[which(AP$`REF-AREA` == 163)] <- "EURO"
AP$Country[which(AP$`REF-AREA` == 967)] <- "RKS"
AP$Country[which(AP$`REF-AREA` == 355)] <- "CUW+SMX"
AP$Country<-as.factor(AP$Country)
AP$v1<-AP$A.PI.T/2
AP$v2<-AP$v1

str(AP)

'data.frame':   11452 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Country : Factor w/ 142 levels "ABW","AFG","ALB",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ REF-AREA: Factor w/ 142 levels "512","299","258",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Year    : chr  "2008-Q2" "2008-Q3" "2008-Q4" "2009-Q1" ...
 $ A.PI.T  : num  -113146 -321591 -1000741 16685590 540591 ...
 $ v1      : num  -56573 -160796 -500370 8342795 270295 ...
 $ v2      : num  -56573 -160796 -500370 8342795 270295 ...
```

As you see I have three numerical variables and another variables `Year` supposed to capture dates. In the meantime, There is a categorical variable `Country`.

My scope is to create charts for EVERY category in `Country`.

The type of chart I want is a mixure of stacked bar and a line type chart, where I want to have an option to pre-specify the range of dates, for example I want from 2012-Q1 to 2015Q3. To give you a better idea of how the chart should look like,  I did an example in Excel, for the `Euro` in `Country`

[image]

In the ideal case, I want to export all the charts that should be created for every level in `Country` into a convenient form where non-R users can use and explore.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like the following (shown only for EURO and UKR):

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(AP, id=1:3)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df[df$Country %in% c('EURO', 'UKR'),], aes(Year, value, fill=variable)) + 
   geom_bar(stat='identity') +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5)) + 
   facet_wrap(~Country, scales='free')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but to add the line as in the picture and specify the range of the dates   are important.